# Хранение бюджета пользователя в MySQL

Tags: sql, безопасность, mysql

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше хранить бюджет пользователя в mysql.

Лучше хранить бюджет в той же таблице, где и вся информация о пользователе или же создать отдельную таблицу `budget_users` и хранить там?

Есть ли ещё какие-нибудь способы дополнительной защиты бюджета?

А у меня родилась идея:
если я буду хранить в базе бюджет и ещё бюджет в зашифрованном виде (например, буду подставлять справа и слева значения `md5('Gg6&*:'.$budjet.'R%;i')`). А когда пользователь попробует вывести деньги, я сверю бюджет с зашифрованым бюджетом. Как считаете, такой способ будет пладотворен?

Comment: Отдельную, foreign key на primary key таблицы сотрудников + On delete cascade

Comment: @AlexWinHope, почему по-вашему в отдельную? Ещё и ключи плодить. Ещё не мешало бы отметить, что то, о чем Вы говорите будет работать с InnoDB только (из бесплатных)

Comment: @Виталий Кустов - все адекватные люди и так юзают InnoDB (за исключением редкого случае необходимости fulltext индекса)

Вообще я так понимаю вам надо читнуть о [нормальных формах](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0)

Comment: Формы это здорово. Но тогда и ответ должен быть наверное другим. Если @Артур Лоденев желает работать с бюджетом как с сущностью, то с бОльшей вероятностью более грамотным решением будет вынести его в отдельную таблицу. Ежели бюджет у него всего-навсего атрибут сущности, то зачем лишняя таблица и ключи?

UPD: Сам лично сталкивался с хостингами, где InnoDB просто нет. Ужасно, но факт

Comment: @Виталий Кустов - если речь о финансах, я полагаю - InnoDB там будет.
Более обширный ответ вы написали сами, я же просто ответил максимально кратко, без освящения причин

Answer (score 2):

Вместе с пользовательскими данными. Для безопасности никому не давайте доступ к базе, а так все ок.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо большое за быстрый отзыв!

Answer (score -1):

Отдельная таблица, причём с полем типа дата, полями увелчение, уменьшение, для того, чтобы можно было получить "бюджет" на дату.